# How to handle advertisement pop ups in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

[sample popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmBRR.jpg)

I am writing a python script that uses selenium chromedriver to take screenshots of websites. However, most websites have alerts and advertisement pop ups including but not limited to accept cookies alert, google translate alert, etc. I have shared a sample image showing ad pop up. I want to be able to close all of these pop ups and alerts so they do not appear in the screenshots. Does anyone know how this can be done? It is important to note that every website implements the pop ups and alerts differently

I am new to selenium and web scraping in general, please can someone guide me.

Comment: There's no general way, you might have to write one of two lines of code per site to click the right button, or at least define the button to click in some way.

Comment: @KlausD. I want to be able to close pop-ups in new unseen websites as well. Is there any other way I can take a screenshot bypassing selenium chromedriver all together?

Comment: Frankly speaking, to qualify for a Stack Overflow questions you have to come up with a real programming question that involves code. You haven't presented any.

Comment: Selenium cannot differentiate between a useless popup and the main browser window. You will have to make that distinction yourself and use the switch windows utility. You'd need to know the something about the main window and add code which closes all other windows which doesn't have the content you expect only on the main window.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)